# package status in *Help* doesn't refresh after install

Tags: package, emacs24.4

I've noticed that since updating to Emacs 24.4, installing packages doesn't refresh their status after installation. If I install, it still appears available to install. How can I force it to refresh?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about the package menu. If so, what does the Help buffer have to do with it?

Comment: If you click on a package in package-menu. The buffer called `*Help*` pops up with package details including dependencies,  categories, other available versions, and basic readme documentation--as well as an [Install] button.

Comment: I'd show a picture, but my Emacs is currently inoperable due to failed updating of Elpa.

Comment: looking at the picture, I suppose it says that it's already installed, and leaves the install button there.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Are you sure that it wasn't like this before you upgraded to 24.4?

Comment: Hmm... actually, I don't remember it saying "Installed from melpa" before. I'm remaking my init.el right now because everything fell apart, so maybe starting from a clean slate fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the *Help* for packages changed in 24.4 so that the information I thought wasn't getting updated *is* and is shown on the **Other versions** line.